# qemu -enable-kvm *slower* than pure emulation for x86_64

Tags: linux, virtualization, linux-kvm, qemu

Running `qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -cpu host -smp cores=4` hosted on an Intel Xeon/Core-2 (newgen, Family=6) or better machine (total number of cores on guest=24, total ram=196gb), and the guest kernel hangs for several minutes and the host kernel pushes messages like:

> kvm: SMP vm created on host with unstable TSC; guest TSC will not be reliable 
>   kvm [..]: vcpu0, guest rIP: 0xffffffff81064724 disabled perfctr wrmsr: 0xc2 data 0xffff

Removing `-enable-kvm -cpu host` ... the guest system becomes *faster!?*

What gives?

Comment: What kernel versions are you using on either side? Could it be related to a bug, fixed by the patch [x86/tsc: Fix erroneous TSC rate on Skylake Xeon](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/arch/x86/kernel/tsc.c?id=b511203093489eb1829cb4de86e8214752205ac6)?

Answer (score 2):

Well it turns out that issue is the clock source used by kvm on the host system.   Have a look at the output of:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource
```

if it's `tcs` or `tcs_early` you have found the culprit, change it to one of the other available clock sources on your system:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource
```

For example hpet (high performance event timer):

```
$ echo hpet | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource
```

Comment: Any chance of an explanation of why `tcs` is a bad clock source to use compared to others? Are there any other downsides or benefits to changing the clock source?

Comment: Possible information on the why from Intel (https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/06/20/eliminate-the-dreaded-clocksource-is-unstable-message-switch-to-tsc-for-a-stable) but I'm not convinced as it mentions the Xeon Phi as problematic and not supporting invariant tsc.

Comment: I didn't get into figuring out why tcs clock is a bad source, just didn't have the time to go around hacking kvm code. I'll probably run some tests after the silly project that I have going gets done. However it's definitely the culprit, because the problem is easily reproduced on multiple hardwares with several permutations